# Child components are not dragged with parent after react state update in Framer Motion v2

Tags: framer-motion

I am building a [Trello](https://trello.com/) alternative where you can create lists and tasks. It should be possible to reorder the lists (horizontally) and the tasks within a list (vertically) by dragging the elements.

I am facing a problem when dragging a list, the tasks within that list are not following the parent:

[image: Trello alternative prototype]

I've been trying to figure out in what circumstances the drag propagation does not work, and made [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-reorder-animation-wh5be):

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

export const Example = () => {
  const [colors, setColors] = useState(initialColors);
  const [isDragging, setDragging] = useState(false);

  return (
    <motion.ul
      drag
      dragConstraints={{ top: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0, left: 0 }}
      dragElastic={0.5}
      style={{ background: "yellow" }}
    >
      {colors.map(background => (
        <motion.li
          key={background}
          drag
          dragConstraints={{ top: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0, left: 0 }}
          dragElastic={0.5}
          style={{ background }}
          // Uncomment this to get slightly different behavior
          // onDragStart={() => setDragging(true)}
          // onDragEnd={() => {
          //   setDragging(false);
          // }}
        />
      ))}
    </motion.ul>
  );
};

const initialColors = ["#FF008C", "#D309E1", "#9C1AFF", "#7700FF"];
```

[image: Simple example of drag progogation breaking]

I think the problem I'm facing in this simple codesandbox example might be the same as in my Trello alternative app. If you uncomment the `onDragStart` and `onDragEnd` lines (which simply stores a "drag state" boolean, without actually using it for anything), then all child boxes stops following the parent on drag after one of them has been moved.

**So my question is:**

How do I make the child components draggable while preserving the original behavior when dragging the parent container? Also if possible, why does this happen?

I have tried adding the `dragPropogation` prop to the parent without any success.

**Note that I am using the newly released version 2 of Framer Motion!**
I could make this work fairly well in version 1.*, but even there I stumbled on a few problems which made me want to try if it was easier in version 2

Comment: I wrote an issue with framer-motion: https://github.com/framer/motion/issues/636